# Поместить переменную во вложенную функцию

Tags: javascript, переменные, функции

Есть функция, в ней еще одна функция, которая вызывается при успешном выполнении. 
В основной функции заполняется массив данных. Мне необходимо использовать этот массив во вложенной функции. Как передать его туда?

```
  function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var latitude=[], longitude=[];
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){

     latitude[i] =  results.rows.item(i).latitude;
     longitude[i] = results.rows.item(i).longitude;

    }

    var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

}

var  count = 0;
var latitude , longitude ;

function onSuccess(position) {
 //Как в эту функцию поместить массив longitude[]  ?
}
```

Пробовал вот так, не помогает:

```
  function onSuccess(position, longitude[]) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать примерно.

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {onSuccess(position, longitude);}, onError, options);
}
//.....
function onSuccess(position, longitude) {
```

Comment: Если массив надо передать, то longitude или longitude[] нужно передавать?

Comment: longitude, где вы взяли синтаксис  longitude[] ?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на сколько рационально,но поробуйте эти 2 варианта:

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
var longitude=[];
longitude.push(tx);
   function onSuccess(position) {
         longitude.push(position);
       console.log( longitude);
    }
  return onSuccess
}
var x=querySuccess('help');
x('position');

 function querySuccess(tx, position) {
    var longitude=[];
    longitude.push(tx);
       function onSuccess(pos) {
             longitude.push(pos);
           console.log( longitude);
        }
     onSuccess(position);
    }
    querySuccess('help','position');
```